# Weird insert problem with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I got a list that i wan't to interrupt via javascript to add a title:

From:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="afterthis">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

To:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="afterthis">2</li>
</ul>
<h1>Title</h1>
<ul>
    <li>3</li>    
    <li>4</li>    
</ul>
```

i thought that was easy by doing: `$(".afterthis").after("</ul><h1>Title</h1><ul>");`

but it doesn't close the list, it moves the end tag, it inserts `<h1>Title</h1><ul></ul>`

to see the problem see this jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Fx74b/14/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery works with valid HTML only, not string parts.

So you cannot pass broken html to the `after()` method.

You will need to split the `ul` your self and add the other elements in between.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var splitelement = $(".afterthis"); // find the element which will be used for the split
    var ul = splitelement.parent(); // find the relative ul
    var newul = $('<ul>'); // create the new ul that will follow the existing one

    newul.append( splitelement.nextAll() ); // move the rest of the li elements to the new ul
    ul.after("<h1>Title</h1>").next().after(newul); // insert the title and then then ul
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ph5UM/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `.after` needs an argument which is a proper DOM text or object.
`$(</ul><h1>Title</h1><ul>)` is started from an end tag so `</ul>` is ignored. `<ul>` is not finished to jquery added an end tag for `<ul>`